# Website creation query

Tags: ajax, web, web-hosting

I need to create a website which stores the list of all games the player has played and it shows right on your profile. As the player goes on completing a game, he adds the game into his list.
So i would need a basic lo-gin configuration and then by using AJAX, I will populate the list of games which he wants to add to his list. So that he can track the list with games that he has played.
So now I need suggestion on how to go on with it?
How to start building?
Which language do I need to pickup?
I am well versed with Java and j2ee.
Is this enough?
Also I am a freelancer so I can't afford to pay for a website. So any free website hosting service which will help me to build the website which I have in mind??
Also if I use any free website hosting service, will they provide me with a database and AJAX capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic setup:

1. You need a domain first. Try to pick something unique, as it will be cheaper. You can find one on namecheap: https://www.namecheap.com
2. You need hosting. Again, go with namecheap.
3. To start building, you need to learn some HTML and CSS. HTML is markup of the web, and CSS is the stylesheet of the web. They aren't hard languages to start off in. You can start for free at Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css
4. I believe namecheap offers database support as well. Ajax isn't provided by a hosting service. It's more of a group of languages (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).

This should get you going. I can't really give you more detailed information than this because your question is really broad. If you Google your questions, you'll get good answers and guides.

Best of luck.

Comment: I have recently undergone a training in HTML, CSS ,JavaScript.So I am quite familiar with the basics of it all.But I have no knowledge about website hosting. The website that you mentioned offers cheap domains but I am on the lookout for something free.Can you mention something along that line?

Comment: If you search Google for free web hosting, you'll find a lot of options. But, if you're looking for reliability and safety, you should look for a paid option.